# activerecord, refactoring the source code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have three tables

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :lexemes, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Lexeme < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :word
end

class Word < AR::Base
  has_many :lexemes
end
```

This code is storing the word to Words table and assign it to the user.

```
word = Word.where(:word=>token).first_or_create
lexeme = @user.lexemes.where(:word_id=>word.id).first_or_create
```

I don't like my code, so is it possible to improve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :lexemes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many  :words, :through => :lexemes
end

class Lexeme < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :word
end

class Word < AR::Base
  has_many :lexemes
  has_many :users, :through => :lexemes
end
```

You should normally be able to create word by following code but it seems there is [a bug in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5325).

```
word = @user.words.find_or_create_by_word(token)
```

Therefore I have changed the model to following. You may remove it when the bug is fixed.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lexemes
  has_many :words, :through => :lexemes do
        def find_or_create_by_word(token)
            find_by_word(token) || create(:word => token)
        end
  end
end
```

Comment: `first_or_create` considered to be a clearer alternative for `find_or_create_by_xxx`

Comment: @Alexey it had the same bug, overriding find_or_create_by_xxx was a better option. Thanks for the tip.